# Change url through htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

This is my htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I want to change may site link from

> http://woocommerce.demostage.net/vendors/admin2-shop/

to

> http://admin2-shop/woocommerce.demostage.net

Is it possible???

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like changing  http://woocommerce.demostage.net/vendors/admin2-shop/ to http://admin2-shop.woocommerce.demostage.net, so you use a subdomain then. A subdomain, seperated by a slash (`/`) is not working.

But this is not working with htaccess, you just have to set up that subdomain and then you can load your content there.

Answer (score 1):

**No**. you can't have a subdomain separated by a forward slash. You can have a subdomain seperated by a dot such as: `http://admin2-shop.woocommerce.demostage.net` but not `http://admin2-shop/woocommerce.demostage.net`.

In order to set up a subdomain you need to create a subdomain at a DNS level, point it to your server and set-up the appropriate configuration at your web server level.